# Real-time Operation systems and attacks

Tags: attacks, scada

I'm interested on kind of attacks which can be used on 'Industry Control Systems'.

I only have found that following malwares:

- switching-off/disablement the systems
- stole the information

What else consequences can be occurred?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but one more issue is that many of these installations have relatively poor security measures - like default passwords, etc. and rely mainly one physical disconnection from other networks or security by obscurity (another explanation is that they are of the 'radar' of security personnel who traditionally target conventional IT systems)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you really need to rethink the question, however to answer what I think you are asking (what effects can an attack on SCADA systems have) then the list would have to include:

- Switching off Power
- Information theft
- Destruction of power plants (through
  overload, oscillation, over-pressure,
  disabling of safety cutouts etc - see the [generator destruction video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJyWngDco3g) IOActive showed at Defcon)
- Environmental damage (opening of oil
  pipelines, opening of hydroelectric
  valves incorrectly etc)
- Processes running inefficiently (eg
  the effect Stuxnet had on centrifuges
  producing essential products for the
  nuclear industry)

Basically, anything that is controlled by a SCADA system is at risk - so it's kind of the same question as "what damage can an attack on an IT system do?" - it all depends on what the IT system does.

If you can clarify your question as per the FAQ, we could definitely give you more appropriate answers.

Update: [Dozens of exploits released for SCADA systems](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/22/scada_exploits_released/). some more info for you.

Comment: Your answer is what I wanted to know! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @davs - feel free to click the little tick icon on my answer. On stack exchange that works even better than thanks :-)

Comment: ♦ : Ok. Sorry.. I've forgot :(

Comment: @davs - no worries. welcome to security se. The FAQ is useful to read, both because it helps people to answer questions appropriately, but also because it can help you to write questions to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Seriuos economic problem for a country. Example the Siberian Gas Pipeline Explosion in 1982[1](http://www.risidata.com/Database/Detail/cia-trojan-causes-siberian-gas-pipeline-explosion)

Comment: Can you provide some reference which backs that this explosion was the consequence of an cyberattack?

Comment: http://www.risidata.com/Database/Detail/cia-trojan-causes-siberian-gas-pipeline-explosion

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/us-software-blew-up-russian-gas-pipeline/

Comment: this things are secrets but ¿how know? Only in book of memories are exposed

Comment: This story is no longer considered credible by informed sources. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44212/did-the-cia-blow-up-a-siberian-pipeline-in-1982